# System.Reflection.TargetException (Object does not match target type)

Tags: asp.net-core, system.reflection

I get System.Reflection.TargetException (Object does not match target type) in prop.GetValue(t).

The method receives an array of JSON objects and I use the ParamsQuery class as DTO to match the data. I need to get the value that properties 2-6 contain to concatenate a string.

Thgank you

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Ficha>>> GetFichas(List<ParamsQuery> paramsQuery)
    {
        foreach (ParamsQuery pq in paramsQuery)
        {
            Type t = pq.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] propsInfo = t.GetProperties();

            foreach (var prop in propsInfo)
            {
                var propVal = prop.GetValue(t);
                ...
            }
        }

        return await ...
    }

    public class ParamsQuery
    {
        public string Campo { get; set; }
        public string Operador { get; set; }
        public string Criterio1 { get; set; }
        public string Criterio2 { get; set; }
        public string Criterio3 { get; set; }
        public string Criterio4 { get; set; }
        public string Criterio5 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: prop.GetValue(t); t should be `ParamsQuery` type, not `Type` type.

Answer (score 0):

Change it like below:

```
    foreach (ParamsQuery pq in paramsQuery)
    {
        Type t = pq.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] propsInfo = t.GetProperties();

        foreach (var prop in propsInfo)
        {
            var propVal = prop.GetValue(pq);
            ...
        }
    }
```